# unable to get popup with jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jquery plugin to show popup

when i use a url for plugin,i get a popup

```
 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

but when i use local source from downloaded plugin...i am unable to show popup

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"href="./src/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" type="text/css">
 <script src="./src/jsLibraries/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./src/jsLibraries/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

unable to get over this error....i downloaded plugin from jquery-mobile website

Comment: check your src URLs. they're probably coming back as 404.

Comment: As @ferrants points out below, you need to include jquery before jquery.mobile

Answer (score 6):

Try including jquery before jquery.mobile. Pretty sure the latter requires the former.

Comment: thanks a lot buddy.....if you in bangalore.... let me know...i owe you a big treat....

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to give type="text/javascript" in the script tag. Also do check your src of the files.